# Check whether many-to-many relationship exists Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following Models:

```
/* Team.php */

class Team extends Eloquent {

  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
  }

}

/* User.php */

class User extends Eloquent {

  public function teams() {
    return $this->hasMany('Team');
  }

}
```

and database structure:

```
teams
  id
  user_id
  name

users
  id
  email

team_user
  id
  team_id
  user_id
```

A user can create (and own - hence teams.user_id) a team, but also belong to other teams.

If possible, I'd like to be able to get all the teams for a particular user using Eloquent without doing a custom SQL query like so:

```
 SELECT teams.* 
 FROM teams 
 JOIN team_user 
 ON (team_user.team_id = teams.id) 
 WHERE team_user.user_id = ?
```

The custom SQL query works but I'm convinced this isn't the native way to go about this in Laravel.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be returning `$this-belongsToMany(Model::class)` on both sides of the relationship for your pivot table to be used.

```
/* Team.php */

class Team extends Eloquent {

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

}

/* User.php */

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function teams() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }

}
```

<strike>There is no need to have a `user_id` field in teams as this implicitly says `Many-to-one`. (This team has one user only)</strike>

With this fixed up, using eloquent to get all teams for a user would be as simple as:

```
User::teams()->get();
```

And the inverse

```
Team::users()->get();
```

Or to get a user entity with all their teams:

```
User::with('teams')->get();
```

And again vice versa

```
Team::with('users')->get();
```

Comment: Antonio, Josh and yourself are all correct - need the belongsToMany relationship. Think I need to figure out what this will do to the rest of the application as a Team now doesn't have an owner User (which is why the inverse relationship wasn't there to start with.

Comment: There is no reason to get rid of the user_id column on teams if you are using it to determine ownership of that object. That being said, naming the key more appropriately to owner_id or something similar would make more sense.

Comment: @Abba yes that's true, certainly with what the OP said in comments. In fact there's no reason why a specific Many-to-one relationship couldn't be created in parallel with the many-to-many.

Answer (score 10):

To answer to the question in the title, here is how you define a boolean function in the user model to know if the relation exists in the pivot table 'team_user':

```
public function isPartOfThe($team)
{
    return $this->teams()->where('team_id', $team->id)->exists();
}
```

Then you can call the function in your controller as follow:

```
If($user->isPartOfThe($team)
{
    //true
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I like this solution because i think it is friendlier on the database. Rather then selecting all records and iterating through.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are almost there, you already have your relations set so now you just need to:

```
$user = User::find(1);

foreach($user->teams as $team)
{
   echo $team->name;
}
```

Since Laravel will expect a teams_users pivot table name, you might also need to tell it the correct one and use belongsToMany() on both:

```
class Team extends Eloquent {

  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'team_user');
  }

}

class User extends Eloquent {

  public function teams() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Team', 'team_user');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this

```
class User {
    public function teams() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'team_user');
    }
}


class Team {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Team', 'team_user');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to get rid of the user_id column on teams if you are using it to determine ownership of that object.

That being said, naming the key more appropriately to manager_id or something similar would make more sense. Also, nothing dicates that you have to use a relationship function name that is the same as the related (pluralized) table name.

Try something like this in addition to the belongsToMany setup above:

```
<?php
    class Team extends Eloquent {

        ...

        public function manager()
        {
            return belongsTo('User', 'manager_id');
        }

        ...

    }

<?php
    class User extends Eloquent {

        ...

        public function manages()
        {
            return hasMany('Team', 'manager_id');
        }

        ...

    }
```

I don't feel like the previous answers accounted for the data model you were trying for completely.